# Kill Process in VS2012 Package Manager Console

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-2012, nuget

Doe anyone know how to kill a process in the VS2012 Package Manager Console. Pressing Control-C does not seem to kill processes like it does in the standard powershell.

Answer (score 10):

Found it. There is a button on the window in visual studio. I did not see it because of my window configurations.

[image: Kill Process in Package Manager Console]

Comment: Doesn't do anyting.

Comment: If you close the console and try to open it again, it also won't open and the only way to get it back is restart vs.